# Opening text files and saving the contents of the selected files as variables in Tkinter

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to open and read a text file using a dropdown menu

```
subMenu.add_command(label = "Open file", command = OpenFile)
```

I then want to save the text in this file into a variable. I don't understand the askopenfilename stuff and just want to know how a user can choose their file and how I would put that text in a variable.

```
window.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", "*.txt"))
PlainText=open(fileName, 'r')
Entered_Text = PlainText.read()
```

I am given this error,

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\matty\Desktop\Task3Python .py", line 63, in OpenFile
    window.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", "*.txt")))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 375, in askopenfilename
    return Open(**options).show()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 48, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad file type "*.txt", should be "typeName {extension ?extensions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"
```

Comment: _"will this work?"_ Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: No, I got an error. http://prntscr.com/9mh0bj (have to print screen, error too long to comment) Sorry I was asking so vaguely

Comment: Please copy and paste your Exeception message into the question so it is persistent for future generations

Comment: @MatthewPearson Check the other post (that I am suggesting as duplicate), which solves this problem, but essentially it should be like this: `filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", "*.txt"),) )`

Comment: Yes, I took a look and it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @MatthewPearson Nice! Anyway, next time try to search better on Google (which is what I did). If in the first 10 posts that you see you don't have a suggestion for a solution, then probably you should ask a question :)